# change value of edit text when a value is selected from autocomplete

Tags: android

```
public void Add_Item() {

        ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        CustomAutoCompleteTextView a_no = new CustomAutoCompleteTextView(
                getActivity(), null);
        a_no.setId(3);
        a_no.setAdapter(adapter);
        a_no.setHint("Account No");
        a_no.setEms(10);
        a_no.setThreshold(1);
        a_no.setTag("a_no");
        a_no.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        a_no.setOnItemClickListener(autoItemSelectedListner);
        ll.addView(a_no);

                    **EditText d_no = new EditText(getActivity());
            d_no.setId(3);
            d_no.setHint("Description No");
            d_no.setEms(10);
            d_no.setTag("d_no");
            d_no.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            ll2.addView(d_no);**

        ll.addView(ince);
        ly.addView(ll);

    }
  private OnItemClickListener autoItemSelectedListner = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0
                    .getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

            ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) arg0.getParent();


            }


    };
```

In the above code i used Custom auto complete to populate some data.It is workig perfectly.But i need to change the value of the edit text which is located right next to the autocomplete when a value is selected from autocomplete.Here the problem is the autocomplete and edit text are dynamically created when the Additem method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You must use TextWatcher.

```
your_auto_completetextview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            doSomething();



        } 

    });
```

Whenever text within your AutocompleteTextView changes you can perform your necessary task within onTextChanged() method.You can find more details about `TextWatcher` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Comment: thanx for ur reply but problem is hoe i change the value of the edit text which appeared right next to the autocomplete

Comment: no problem just put ed.setText(something) in the onTextchanged()

Comment: @kgandroid If I do so then the text in the edittext will be changed whenever I type a character in the autocomplete textview.

Comment: Then whenever i will write anything in autocomplete then removeTextChangedListener(watcher)) must be called,after setting the text,we must re-enable the listener with addTextChangedListener(watcher)).Also we can use some boolean value to detect the status.That logic must be implemented by the programmer.

Comment: this wayy icannot get the value of the edit text because Edit text are generated dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Make your edit text final,

```
final EditText d_no = new EditText(getActivity());
```

And set the value in the onItemClickListener() of the autocomplete textview,

```
private OnItemClickListener autoItemSelectedListner = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0
                    .getAdapter().getItem(arg2);

            d_no.setText("your_value_here");//To set the value to edittext

            ViewGroup viewgroup = (ViewGroup) arg0.getParent();


            }


    };
```

This will work only if you create only one edittext at a time. If you created more than one then you have to set different tag and then check for the tag when you set the value.

Comment: i try this method .And Count the number of child elements it gives 1 even though i have 3 children

Comment: Which children count?

Comment: parent of the autocomplete is linear layout .it contains 2 children(eg:e_no and d_no)

Comment: Have you used 
ll.getChildCount(); :

Comment: yeah used.not any luck

Comment: In your addItem() method you have instantiate the linear layout. So that the linear layout contains new one with only one child. Instantiate your ll in onCreate() rather than addItem()

Comment: if i do that all dynamically created edit text are loade on a one linear layout.All i want to do is update a edit text right next to the auto complete when the value is selected.If i use ur method then i could not do that

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. You can use an array of ll and then access the particular layout with the position. So that you can access the particular edittext.